# Running tests in TestNG suite xml file sequentially

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I have the following *testng.xml* file. I want testng to run these tests sequentially. I don't want to separate each of these tests into a new file.

```
<suite name="framework-tests" allow-return-values="true" verbose="10">
        <test name="framework-tests-single-program">
            <classes>
                <class name="testngdriver.TestFactory"/>
            </classes>
            <groups>
                <run>
                    <include name="framework-tests" />
                </run>  
            </groups>
            <parameter name="testInterfaceXML" value="programSingleInterface.xml"></parameter>       
            <parameter name="testSuiteXML" value="programTestSingleProgram.xml"></parameter>       
        </test>


        <test name="framework-tests-two-programs">
            <classes>
                <class name="testngdriver.TestFactory"/>
            </classes>
            <groups>
                <run>
                    <include name="framework-tests" />
                </run>  
            </groups>
            <parameter name="testInterfaceXML" value="programTwoInterface.xml"></parameter>       
            <parameter name="testSuiteXML" value="programTestTwoPrograms.xml"></parameter>       
        </test>
    </suite>
```

I have tried combinations of *parallel* = "*tests*", "*classes*", "*methods*" and *thread-count = 1* on suite level,  and none worked.

Comment: What are your expected and actual results? It is not clear what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The tests should run in order provided:

> By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in
>   the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file
>   to be run in an unpredictible order, set the preserve-order attribute
>   to false [[1]](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml)

The *`parallel`* attribute shouldn't be used or you could set it to *'false'*.

Comment: Are you saying that if you set parallel=true then the preserve order is just automatically false even if you try to set it to true?   Seems logical.  Just wanting your opinion on that.